# Extracting columns from multiindex csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, multi-index

I have a csv file that I read into a pandas dataframe

[image]

`platesStatistics= pd.read_csv('cells.csv',index_col=[0,1], header=[0,1])`

[image]

I then want to get all 'mean' columns. I tried

```
platesStatistics['mean']
platesStatistics[:,'mean']
```

but it doesn't work (I also tried some commands with `loc`). What confuses me is that
`platesStatistics['A','mean']` works fine and returns a single series.

What is the right way to get the reduced dataframe? It is important to note that the actual file I'm working with is much larger, so extracting columns explicitly would be hard.

Comment: What should be expected output? MultiIndex (A, B) and `mean` levels or columns `A, B` ?

Comment: I expect to get columns ```A, B```

Comment: Ok, then use `df = platesStatistics.xs('mean', axis=1, level=1)`

Comment: This is exactly what I have been looking for. thanks! I now see that this question has been answered before (I didn't manage to find the answer earlier).